# Finding a nontrivial normal subgroup of a group of rank 36

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a group such that $|G| = 2^2 \cdot 3^2$. I want to show that there exists a nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$.

My tries:
By the Sylow theorem I find out that te number of $2$-Sylow subgroups is equal to 1,3 or 9. On the other side the number of $3$-Sylow subgroups is equal to $1$ or $4$. Now I don't have any ideas what to do.

Comment: Is $G$ non-abelian?

Comment: I can't assume it.